# Concatenating values from SQL select statement

Tags: sql, string, oracle

I am doing a basic SQL select from an oracle database.

```
select DISTINCT spriden_pidm, a.saracmt_comment_text, spriden_id, c.saracmt_comment_text, '2017' as "YEAR", szrspdc_prog_code
from spriden, sarappd, saradap, stvapdc, saracmt a, saracmt c, szrspdc
where blah blah blah
```

The following three fields are used as a key in another system I am doing an import into so I need to get the following into one field: `c.saracmt_comment_text, '2017' as "YEAR", szrspdc_prog_code.`

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: which version of sql? you can use concat from sql 2012, otherwise just do the classic way to concatenating.. 'Hello' + ' World '

Comment: You can use || operator ..something like below

SELECT firstname || ' ' || lastname AS studentname
FROM students;

Comment: Gah. The old obsolete  `A,B` join syntax. It burns us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string concatenation operator in Oracle is `||`. So, you need to use the following query:

```
select DISTINCT 
c.saracmt_comment_text || '2017' || szrspdc_prog_code as key_field
spriden_pidm, a.saracmt_comment_text, spriden_id, 
c.saracmt_comment_text, '2017' as "YEAR", szrspdc_prog_code 
from spriden, sarappd, saradap, stvapdc, saracmt a, saracmt c, szrspdc 
where blah blah blah
```

Comment: thank you! I had tried || but didn't have an as field_name at the end

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do this in PL/Sql or on the receiving end is C#/VB.NET Code?  I assume PL/Sql.

```
Procedute SomeName(DataOut OUT Varchar2) IS
    WResult Varchar2(4000) -- I don't know the size of 2 of the table columns involed so I use the max size of Varchar2 which is 4000
Begin

    select into wResult a.saracmt_comment_text || YEAR || szrspdc_prog_code from
    (
      select DISTINCT spriden_pidm, a.saracmt_comment_text, spriden_id,
      c.saracmt_comment_text, '2017' as "YEAR", szrspdc_prog_code from  
      spriden, sarappd, saradap, stvapdc, saracmt a, saracmt c,
      szrspdc_prog_code where Conditions
    );

   DataOut := wResult;
End;
```

Hope this helps.

R/
Prescott ....